# Creating a Select List + Textfield

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to create a supplies field made up of a select list (or entity reference) and a number field. Users should be able to create several of these.

For example, the link field has a URL and Title element, (but for this supplies field, there would be a select list instead of the URL field).

Try to find a standalone field (rather than using paragraphs or field collection) for ease of use with JSON:API.

Answer (score 0):

Currently looking at:

> The **reference value pair** combines an **entity reference** with a **free text
> value** field in one new field type.
>
> Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_value_pair

Other related projects:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/key_value_field
- https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/pingevt/2760039